# LL1 grammar for simple calculator(+,-,*,/,pow,root)

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I came up with this grammar that manages to sucessfully add/sub numbers in brackets and whatnot. However I find it very difficult to expand it for pow(^) and root(#) logic. I am grateful for any help as Im hardstuck now...

```
nonZeroDigit = "1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|"9";
digit = "0" | nonZeroDigit;
naturalNumber = nonZeroDigit , {digit};
secondPriorityOperators= "+" |"-";
firstPriorityOperators= "*" | "/";
syntax=expr;
expr=term, {secondPriorityOperators, term};
term=factor, {firstPriorityOperators, factor};
factor="(", expr , ")" | naturalNumber;
root = "#" , root | factor;
power = root, "^" , power| root;
```

For testing I used this site: https://planetcalc.com/6385/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add another priority level:

```
thirdPriorityOperators= "+" |"-";
secondPriorityOperators= "*" | "/";
firstPriorityOperators= "#" | "^";

term3rd=term2nd, {thirdPriorityOperators, term2nd};
term2nd=term1st, {secondPriorityOperators, term1st};
term1st=factor, {firstPriorityOperators, factor};
```